# How to wrap last letter of each menu item with a span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a navigation menu, I want to wrap the last letter of every menu item text with a span tag, using jQuery.

Here's my current approach, but it's not working:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').each(function(i) {

    var menuElement = $(this).html();

    var menuElementLenght = menuElement.length;

    var lastChar = menuElement.charAt(menuElementLenght - 1);

    $(lastChar).wrap('<span></span>')

});
```

I think because I'm targeting a stripped string and not an HTML element.

Comment: you need to append that new element back on the original, assuming the wrapping is working, Ill post an example below

Comment: the other answers are better, different ways to do it, I just worked of the code you gave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it simply with `regex`,

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').html(function(_,txt) {
    return txt.replace(/(.$)/, "<span>$1</span>");
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8tuzspps/)

In the language of regex, `(.$)` This will match the last character. `$` denotes the end of the string. And since we grouped it using `()`, we can access the matched group by using `$notation`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html()` as shown :-

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').html(function (index, html) {
  return html.slice(0, html.length - 1) + '<span>' + html.slice(html.length - 1) + '</span>';
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/n0cfdxup/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
 $('p').each(function(index, element) {
    // grab all of the elements you want.
    var $el = $(element);
    var words = $el.text().split(' '); // split the word into letters
    $el.html(''); // delete the old stuff
    // now this code wraps every letter in a span, but you can take if from here!
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      var newSpan = $('<span>').text(words[i] + ' ');
      $el.append(newSpan);
    }
  });
```